# how we use assigment operator (:=) in procedure without cursor

Tags: mysql

i have this query (without procedure)

```
SELECT row_number,current_product_id,prev_product_id FROM
(
    SELECT 
        @row_num:=@row_num+1 AS row_number,
        @pr_product_id AS prev_product_id,
        kd_barang AS current_product_id,
        @pr_product_id:=kd_barang
    FROM m_barang
    CROSS JOIN ( SELECT @row_num :=0 AS row_num) rn
    CROSS JOIN ( SELECT @pr_product_id :='' AS row_num) prev_product_id
) data
LIMIT 5;
```

[with output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gHfQ9.png)

i want to change it into procedure with same output without using cursor , how it will be? thank you

Comment: *i want to change it into procedure with same output without using cursor , how it will be?* ```CREATE PROCEDURE procedure_name {your query};```. PS. Variables usage without definite ORDER BY produces indeterministic output. LIMIT without ORDER BY produces indeterministic output too. So you're playing a lottery..

Comment: thank you for the response. i used limit just only for example, because the real data is too much.. of course in procedure i'm not going to use limit without order,..
i wonder how to convert asignment operator (:=)  in a procedure for this case without cursor, maybe there's simpler way

Comment: What is your MySQL version? PS. The assignment operator does not need to be replaced, it must successfully work in SP.